# reload recaptcha2 Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, recaptcha

I am new in angular 6 and I am using recaptcha in my registration page.
When the form is submitted I have to reload recaptcha to reset value in case you want to submit again. I am using this inside a form:

```
<ngx-recaptcha2 
    #captchaElem
    (expire)="handleExpire()"
    (load)="handleLoad()"
    (success)="handleSuccess($event)"
    [size]="size"
    [hl]="el"
    [theme]="theme"
    id="captcha"
    name="captcha"
    [type]="type">
</ngx-recaptcha2>
```

I can't handle reloading event in angular 6. Any help? thanks

Comment: Having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `ngIf` to achieve this, since that directive will physically reload the component when it's inserted into the DOM. You can achieve this by modifying your `ngx-recaptcha2` component like so:

`<ngx-recaptcha2 *ngIf="showCaptcha" ... >`

Then add this to the top of your controller:

`public showCaptcha = true;`

Now in your `handleSuccess()` event, do the following:

```
public handleSuccess() {
    // ... success logic

    // set to false, which removes component from DOM
    this.showCaptcha = false;

    // let the Angular digest run, then set to True again and the component reloads
    setTimeout(() => {
         this.showCaptcha = true;
    });    

    // note: 2nd param of setTimeout left empty since you just need to wait 
    // for the Angular digest, but you can put a value in here if needed to 
    // delay reloading the component
}
```

You can take that similar approach, preferably abstracted away into its own callable function, when the token expires, or attempts are reached, etc.